# Bash: check if certain command has output: if not execute install on one line

Tags: bash, logstash

In logstash you can check if a certain plugin is installed:

```
ubuntu@xxx:/usr/share/logstash$ bin/logstash-plugin list | grep logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs
logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs
```

Above there is an install (there is output).
Now if there is no output I want to execute:

```
sudo bin/logstash-plugin install /home/ubuntu/logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs-1.0.2.gem
```

otherwise I want to do nothing.
I need to have this in one bash command. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do that with `grep` on an if condition to see if a match is found and install the missing app when it returns a failure error code

```
if bin/logstash-plugin list | grep -q logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    sudo bin/logstash-plugin install /home/ubuntu/logstash-input-cloudwatch_logs-1.0.2.gem
fi
```